# Nuxt Cannot read properties of null (reading '$route')

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js

I'm creating conditional event handlers in this fashion:

```html
<section>@mouseover="this.$route.path === '/' && imgHoverIn"</section>
```

This, however, throws the error

> "Cannot read properties of null (reading '$route')"

I'm able to include the route path as a template literal like this `{{this.$route.path }}` and get the expected result ('/').

Why is the variable on one hand showing up as expected and on the other hand showing up as `null`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need `this` in template. So try with the following directly

```html
<section @mouseover="$route.path === '/' && imgHoverIn"></section>
```

Vue is somehow clever and figures out what you're trying to do when you call `{{ this.$route.path }}`, but it cannot fix the errors for you all the time.

Some ESlint would have told and fixed that for you on the other side.